# How to convert the Binary data received from opc output arguments on the client to data type defined on opc server

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

I have recently added a question here which helped me to connect to an OPC server and call a method on the server and retrieve some data. The problem I am facing now is to I have no clue how am I supposed to convert the received data to a data type which is defined on the Server, on my client to make sense of that data. The output Arguments parameter has the data. The 2nd item on the list is the one I am trying to convert. The Node Id of the output data type on the server is "ns=2;i=15205". Below is the method:

```
public void Connect(string endpointUrl)
        {
            AppSession.UserIdentity = new UserIdentity();
            AppSession.SessionName = "urn:ACGIDT053:UnifiedAutomation:UaExpert";
            //AppSession.Application.CertificateGroups[0];            
            //string endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://212.43.72.27:51510/UA/WipotecServer/";
            AppSession.Connect(endpointUrl, SecuritySelection.None);
            ICertificate certificateServer = SecurityUtils.LoadCertificate(AppSession.EndpointDescription.ServerCertificate);
            AppSession.Application.TrustedStore.Add(certificateServer, true);

            /// [Step 1]
            // parse the object id.
            NodeId objectId = NodeId.Parse("ns=2;i=15108");

            // get the selected method id.            
            NodeId methodId = NodeId.Parse("ns=2;i=15057");

            List<ExtensionObject> ar = new List<ExtensionObject>();

            // get input arguments.
            UInt32 a = 1;
            List<Variant> inputArguments = new List<Variant>
            {
                new Variant(string.Empty, TypeInfo.Scalars.String), new Variant(a,TypeInfo.Scalars.UInt32), new Variant(string.Empty, TypeInfo.Scalars.String),
                new Variant(ar.ToArray(), TypeInfo.Arrays.ExtensionObject), new Variant(string.Empty, TypeInfo.Scalars.String)
            };

            /// [Step 2]
            List<StatusCode> inputArgumentErrors;
            List<Variant> outputArguments = null;            

            // call the method on the server.
            StatusCode error = AppSession.Call(
                objectId,
                methodId,
                inputArguments,
                out inputArgumentErrors,
                out outputArguments);



            AppSession.Disconnect();

        }
```

Updated Code:

```
StatusCode error = AppSession.Call(
                objectId,
                methodId,
                inputArguments,
                out inputArgumentErrors,
                out outputArguments);

            List<ReadValueId> readListIds = new List<ReadValueId>();
            readListIds.Add(new ReadValueId { NodeId = NodeId.Parse("ns=2;i=15059") });
            List<DataValue> dataValues = AppSession.Read(readListIds);
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

An OPC UA Method Node might have some Input and/or Output Arguments.

Those can be found when Browsing the OPC UA Method Node (In your case "ns=2;i=15057")

Then you can use the OPC UA Read Services to access to the value of the Input or Output Arguments. 
**The Array of OpcUa_Argument is actually wrapped in an Array of ExtensionObject !**

The value of both node is an Array of X Argument structure as following:

```
typedef struct _OpcUa_Argument
{
    OpcUa_String        Name;
    OpcUa_NodeId        DataType;
    OpcUa_Int32         ValueRank;
    OpcUa_Int32         NoOfArrayDimensions;
    OpcUa_UInt32*       ArrayDimensions;
    OpcUa_LocalizedText Description;
}
OpcUa_Argument;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Camille G. will work for many I am sure. But, sadly it did not work for me as I was probably not able to understand some specifics about it. So, I thrust my self inside the UA dot net sdk forums for some time and came out with a solution that worked for me. Here is the elaboration:

So the complex object that you get from the method as output is of type "object" in dot net. Sadly the data of the complex data type which is returned is encoded (i think it is binary encoding, but i am not so sure). So basically to get the decoded value we need to initialize a DataTypeManager with the session that you are using to call the opc server method. Then you will need to convert the output argument to DataValue type.

Below is the code that worked for me:

```
StatusCode _errorStatus = _session.Call(_objectId, _methodId, _inputArguments, out _inputArgumentStatus, out _outputArguments);

            DataTypeManager _dataTypeManager = new DataTypeManager(_session);
            DataValue _dataValue = new DataValue(_outputArguments[1]);
            Variant value = _dataValue.WrappedValue;
            ExtensionObject _extensionObject = value.ToExtensionObject();
            GenericEncodeableObject _genericEncodeable = _dataTypeManager.ParseValue(_extensionObject);

            GenericStructureDataType _genericStructuredDataType = _genericEncodeable.TypeDefinition;

            object _decodedOutput = RecurssiveDecode(_genericEncodeable, 4); 

/// <summary>
        /// Decodes a complex opc ua object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="genericEncodeable">Object to decode.</param>
        /// <param name="index">Argument in object to decode and retrieve.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        object RecurssiveDecode(GenericEncodeableObject genericEncodeable, int index = 0)
        {
            GenericStructureDataType _genericStructuredDataType = genericEncodeable.TypeDefinition;
            for (int i = index; i < _genericStructuredDataType.Count; i++)
            {
                // Get the description of the field (name, data type etc.)
                GenericStructureDataTypeField _fieldDescription = _genericStructuredDataType[i];
                // Get the value of the field
                Variant fieldValue = genericEncodeable[i];
                string fieldName = _fieldDescription.Name;

                if (_fieldDescription.ValueRank == -1)
                {
                    if (_fieldDescription.TypeDescription.TypeClass == GenericDataTypeClass.Simple)
                    {
                        // Print the name and the value
                        string fieldValueString = fieldValue.ToString();
                        return fieldValueString;
                    }
                    else if (_fieldDescription.TypeDescription.TypeClass == GenericDataTypeClass.Structured)
                    {
                        // Print the name and call this method again the child
                        RecurssiveDecode((GenericEncodeableObject)fieldValue.GetValue<GenericEncodeableObject>(null));
                    }
                }
                else if (_fieldDescription.ValueRank == 1)
                {
                    // Print the fields name

                    if (_fieldDescription.TypeDescription.TypeClass == GenericDataTypeClass.Simple)
                    {
                        // Print each element
                        Array array = fieldValue.Value as Array;
                        return array;
                    }
                    else if (_fieldDescription.TypeDescription.TypeClass == GenericDataTypeClass.Structured)
                    {
                        // Call this method again foreach element
                        ExtensionObjectCollection extensionObjects = fieldValue.ToExtensionObjectArray();                        
                        foreach (ExtensionObject e in extensionObjects)
                        {
                            RecurssiveDecode((GenericEncodeableObject)fieldValue.GetValue<GenericEncodeableObject>(null));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The method RecurssiveDecode() will get you the decoded object.
[Here is a link that should elaborate more](http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkdotnet/2.4.2/html/L3ClientTutExample28.html)

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.